# How to manage multiple matching intent-filters

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I'am developing an application that uses `<intent-filter>` in order to open content inside an activity when a certain link like `https://url.com/user_name` is clicked.

I have added another **Filter** that matches a similar path like `https://url.com/livevideo?user=example`, but when i click on this second link Android prompts the user to select one of the two intents both on my app.

My first filter:

```
 <intent-filter android:label="App Name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="url.com"
                android:pathPrefix=""
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

My second filter:

```
 <intent-filter android:label="Watch Live"
            android:order="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="url.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/livevideo"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Is there a way to launch directly only one of the two filters? Like using `android:order` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might consider posting a [mcve] showing how you are setting up your `<intent-filter>` elements. But, if `user_name` is supposed to be a variable piece, I don't see how your URL system works in general (e.g., what if a user signs up with a user name of `livevideo`?).

Comment: My app already handle this kind of problem, because at the sign up moment some names are not available for subscription

Comment: That is a fragile solution, as now you have to remember to edit your signup logic every time that you want to add a new page (and you will be blocked out of pages representing already-registered users). I recommend that you use a different URL system, with a distinct prefix for all variable paths (e.g., `/u/user_name` for user profiles).

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, you can de-prioritize your more general intent filter by using a negative value for the `android:priority` attribute. Note that the default priority is zero and positive priorities are ignored.

However, the big problem with using this approach is that your general intent filter won't just be lower priority than your more specific intent filter. It'll also be lower priority than most intent filters in other apps. In particular, if you're matching `android.intent.action.VIEW` for an `https` URI, you'll be lower priority than the user's web browser. So in practice, your lower priority intent filter will never match at all.

`android:priority` may still be useful in other cases, particularly when providing a "last resort" match for an intent filter that the user may not have any other apps for. But for the specific example you've raised, the only good solution is to rethink your approach. You either want intent filters that don't overlap, or a single combined intent filter that matches everything on your site.